# Is there any T4 template or custom tool to generate class from .resw file?

Tags: c#, localization, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm trying to add localization to class library in my hobby project (WinRT application). I'm surprised that it doesn't generate strongly typed class for resources (.resw file). Is there any T4 template or custom tool to generate such class from resources automatically?

I wrote simple T4 template myself but I wonder if there is any built-in or MS provided mechanism because custom solution has some disadvantages (for example saving changes to resources doesn't trigger T4 transformation).

Comment: Could you explain why you still need a class for your resources? WinRT supports XAML binding your resources.

Comment: @Bart: Because not everything is defined in XAML. You can have custom library and it again offers only .resw file. If the library for example contains some logic which must be localized you need to access resources from code.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my original solution (but it doesn't work in VS 2012 RC for Windows 8 because it [probably doesn't support Text templating](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/toolsforwinapps/thread/8cf38a11-27cd-462b-bf57-107b6ac2baae)). You just need to configure the template to point to the correct resource file by setting `inputFilePath` in the template.

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml.Linq" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.CSharp" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#
    DTE env = GetVSEnvironment();
    var inputFilePath = @"Resources\Strings\en\Resources.resw";
    var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    string className = CreateClassName(provider);

    SetCurrentDirectory();
    if (File.Exists(inputFilePath)) {
#>
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources;

namespace <#= GetNamespace() #> {
    public static class <#= className #> {
        private static ResourceLoader _resourceLoader;

        static <#= className #>() {
            _resourceLoader = new ResourceLoader("<#= GetResourcePath(env) #>");
        }
<#
        foreach (string name in GetResourceKeys(inputFilePath)) {
#>
        public static string <#= provider.CreateEscapedIdentifier(name) #> {
            get { return _resourceLoader.GetString("<#= name #>"); }
        }
<#
        }
#>
    }
}
<#
    } else {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(String.Format("Unable to find Resource file: {0}", inputFilePath)); 
    } 
#>
<#+
    private DTE GetVSEnvironment() {
        DTE env = null;
        var provider = Host as IServiceProvider;
        if (provider != null) {
            env = provider.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
        }

        if (env == null) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Template must be executed from Visual Studio");
        }

        return env;
    }

    private void SetCurrentDirectory() {
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Host.ResolvePath(""));
    }

    private string CreateClassName(CSharpCodeProvider provider) {
        string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Host.TemplateFile);
        return provider.CreateEscapedIdentifier(name);
    }

    private string GetNamespace() {
        return Host.ResolveParameterValue("directiveId", "namespaceDirectiveProcessor", "namespaceHint");
    }

    private string GetResourcePath(DTE env) {
        Project project = env.Solution.FindProjectItem(Host.TemplateFile).ContainingProject;
        string assemblyName = project.Properties.Item("AssemblyName").Value.ToString();
        return assemblyName + "/Resources";
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetResourceKeys(string filePath) {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
        return doc.Root.Elements("data").Select(e => e.Attribute("name").Value);
    }
#>
```

I thought I will solve the issue by normal custom tool used for .resx file but Metro style application requires different namespaces to be used.

Comment: it just works like a charm!!! Thank you very much, It works perfectly with vs2012 RC and windows 8 metro, but need to hardcode the resource file path.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(this.Host.TemplateFile)
```

may help you to get the absolute T4 Template file path(only when executed within visual studio) then just a matter of giving the relative file path of the resources file.

```
var inputFilePath =System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(this.Host.TemplateFile) 
+ "\\Resources\\Strings\\en\\Resources.resw" ;
```

works ok for me

if you want to climb up to the folder ( ..// won't work here ) you can manually edit the string and use it

Answer (score 1):

I just started a Visual Studio 2012 Custom Tool project called [ResW File Code Generator](http://reswcodegen.codeplex.com) on CodePlex

Answer (score 1):

I have a T4 template that provides strongly-generated resources from RESW files at https://github.com/damieng/DamienGKit/tree/master/T4/ResourceGenerator

Just drop the ResourceGeneratorMetro.tt and ResourceGenerator.ttinclude files in your project and modify line 6 of ResourceGeneratorMetro.tt to include the resource names you want it to generate.